# 0xC06D007E: Module not found when trying to use deferred DLL loading

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I'm trying to use an external DLL, writing the code in Visual Studio 2010 Express.

To be specific, I use FFTW as an external library (a fast Fourier transform library). I added the .h file to the project, set the proper linker properties, added the fftw library path to "répertoire de bibliothèques supplémentaires" ("directory containing additional libraries") in the "general" tab of the linker property tab, and finally added added the name of the .lib file in the "Dépendances supplémentaires" ("other dependencies") field and the name of the .dll file in the "Chargement différé des DLL" ("DLL delayed loading") field, both in the "entrée" (input) tab.

If I don't put the .dll file in my project file, I get an error that says `0xC06D007E: Module not found`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a runtime issue. All the IDE settings that you discuss relate to the compilation and linking. But your issue arises at runtime.

DLLs are loaded at runtime and the system looks for them using the [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx). Clearly you need your DLL to be found by that search. The simplest, and usually the preferred, way to achieve this is to place the DLL in the same directory as the executable.